# Eigenvalue Problem in orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $L$ is an eigenspace of $P$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, i.e. $Pv=v$. Let's also assume that $w$ is another vector in $L_\perp$ (the orthogonal complement of $L$) and $Pw = \lambda w$. So, then this $\lambda$ the eigenvalue is not $1$. I would like to know why? Please provide a proof if possible. The problem does not consider complex values.

Comment: Is $L$ *an* eigenspace or *the* eigenspace associated to $1$?  My guess is that $L$ is intended to be the space of all vectors with eigenvalue $1$.  Hence, by definition, any other eigenvector doesn’t have eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: L is an eigenspace associated with 1. Could you please elaborate your definition that you are talking about. Thanks

Comment: What I’m asking is if $L$ is defined to be the span of some eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ or all eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: L is the eigenspace that consists of all vectors that has the eigenvalue 1. L is the the axis of rotation and P is the orthogonal matrix. Then, v is the vector that lies on L and Pv=v. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Phantom, then Michael basically answered your question. The only thing that maybe should be added that the intersection of $L$ and its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$. So, one would have to make the addition that $w\neq0$.

Comment: For future posts, please use MathJax for math text and not plain text like you did. Also, as mentioned in the comments, be more complete with your posts, as it was written, it was not necessarily true. And you likely won't get help for a complete proof if you haven't shown any work towards one yourself.

Comment: @Manatee Since my question considers w as an eigenvector, then by definition of eigenvector w is not equal to zero. So, the information that you provided is unnecessary.

Comment: @Micheal Burr Thank you professor for such a short explanation that I obviously missed.

Comment: @Phantom, the zero vector is always an eigenvector of any linear map, for any eigenvalue. So the restriction is not unnecessary.

Comment: @Manatee Eigenvectors are by definition nonzero. Please put a reference, if you disagree and I would like to know where it says that a zero vector can be an eigenvector. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134228/discussion-between-manatee-pink-and-phantom).

Comment: @Phantom It is possible (and generally *desirable*) to define the term "eigenvalue" to mean a non-zero scalar.  However, it is not *necessary* to do so, and not all authors bother.  As a very quick reference, the top result for "eigenvalue" in my Google bubble is https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html , which does not specifically indicate that an eigenvalue must be nonzero.  If you mean to say that an eigenvalue is a nonzero vector such that $Ax = \lambda x$ for some (eigen)vector $x$, it is helpful to be explicit about this.

Comment: @XanderHenderson If I'm reading the discussion correctly, it's more about zero not being an eigenvector, not an eigenvalue - but maybe I'm skipping over the comment that you're referring to.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Indeed---there were some comments in chat and some deleted comments which further confused the issue.  But my point still remains:  *everything* in mathematics is defined by people, and different authors may use the same word to mean subtly different things (for example, I usually read $\ge$ as "greater than", because I am an analyst, and nothing is every actually equal to anything else).  If someone expresses confusion about a definition, *demanding* that the person produce a reference is kind of rude.  Wouldn't it just be easier to say "Ah!  Yes, I mean a *nonzero* vector."

Comment: Just to clarify some confusion. I never intended any of my comments to be rude. I could have flat out said that expecting an eigenvector to be zero was wrong but I wanted to see where Mantee was getting the wrong information from. Earlier, I requested the moderator to delete the wrong statement that said an eigenvector could be zero, but instead my comment got deleted. I think that was inappropriate. Anyway, this discussion has gone well beyond its intended purpose. I am going to close this comment by giving the credit where it is due. Thanks @MichaelBurr.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified by the OP in the comments, $L$ is the eigenspace of $P$ corresponding to the eigenvector $1$.  In other words, it is the vector space spanned by all of the eigenvectors with associated eigenvalue $1$.

In this case, since the orthogonal complement of $L$ has trivial intersection with $L$, any eigenvector (recall that $0$ is not an eigenvector) in the orthogonal complement must have a different eigenvalue by the definition of $L$.

Note that the orthogonal complement of $L$ does not necessarily contain all other eigenvectors of $P$.  In other words, there may be an eigenvector of $P$ that is not in $L$ (and, hence, has associated eigenvalue other than $1$), but is not orthogonal to $L$.  If $P$ has some additional properties, such as being symmetric, however, then orthogonality is guaranteed.